# How to prevent div size from changing when a button padding is increased?

Tags: html, css

Everytime i change the padding on the buttton, the size of the nav bar increases along with it, and the other items looks unalligned when it changes size. Can someone tell me how to either align the text as the nav bar size increases or tell me some other way around this plz. Thx.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}


/* NAV BAR */

nav {
  overflow: hidden;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
  font-size: 1.4em;
  padding: 31px 15px;
}

li {
  list-style: none;
}

ul {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
  background: #FEFCD7;
  padding: 30px;
}

#online {
  background: teal;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 10%;
  font-size: 1.3em;
  /* PRoblem */
  padding: 5px 10px;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">bleep</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">bloop</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">blap</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">bleepy</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">blab</a></li>
    <button id="online">Plap Online</button>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}


/* NAV BAR */

nav {
  /* Try giving your nav a height and width so your code cannot modify it*/
  height: 100px;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
  font-size: 1.4em;
  padding: 31px 15px;
}

li {
  list-style: none;
}

ul {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
  background: #FEFCD7;
  padding: 30px;
}

#online {
  background: teal;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 10%;
  font-size: 1.3em;
  /* PRoblem */
  /* Use margin, it works for me */
  margin-top: -18px;
  padding: 20px 10px;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">bleep</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">bloop</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">blap</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">bleepy</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">blab</a></li>
    
    <button id="online">Plap Online</button>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: Let me know if I answered your question.. This works for me but I am sure there are other ways.

Comment: I added a vh height and it sorta fixed the problem, the height doesn't change anything after 15vh for some reason but thats probably bc of the other code i didn't include but, ill probably find a way to fix that, thank you for the help. @Reydel